# analogue of Fourier transform where i is replaced by $sqrt{i}$

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelets

For some reason complicated to explain, I am interested in the operator $T$ which to some test function $\Phi$ associates $$T\Phi(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{jxw}\Phi(v)dv$$
where $j=(1+\imath)/\sqrt{2}$. Has anyone seen such a transform? Or is there a general class of transforms from which it is a particular case?

Comment: It's a slice of the bilateral Laplace transform, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
$$
T\Phi(x)=\mathcal F\Phi\Bigl(\frac{j}{i}\,cx\Bigr).
$$